# Can't scroll after lightning component quick action finished

Tags: quickaction, lightning-components, scrolling

I have implemented this Lightning component quick action and it works fine.

[Lightning Web Component LWC Quick Action button Lead Ownership](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324883/lightning-web-component-lwc-quick-action-button-lead-ownership/325290#325290)

The only issue I'm having is that when the button is clicked and the action is ran the record page can't be scrolled unless the page is refreshed.

I have test on Chrome "Version 90.0.4430.212" and Firefox 87.0 and both are showing this issue.

Any idea on what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue